# OpenVPN Client. External certificate signing failed

Tags: openvpn, openvpn-connect

I try to use OpenVPN client in Win10 and I get the following log:

```
[Dec 13, 2021, 21:32:41] Tunnel Options:V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1524,tun-mtu 1500,proto 
TCPv4_CLIENT,comp-lzo,cipher AES-256-GCM,auth [null-digest],keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-client
[Dec 13, 2021, 21:32:41] Creds: UsernameEmpty/PasswordEmpty
[Dec 13, 2021, 21:32:41] Peer Info:
IV_VER=3.git::d3f8b18b
IV_PLAT=win
IV_NCP=2
IV_TCPNL=1
IV_PROTO=30
IV_CIPHERS=AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:CHACHA20-POLY1305
IV_LZO_STUB=1
IV_COMP_STUB=1
IV_COMP_STUBv2=1
IV_IPv6=0
IV_AUTO_SESS=1
IV_GUI_VER=OCWindows_3.3.3-2562
IV_SSO=webauth,openurl,crtext

[Dec 13, 2021, 21:32:41] EVENT: EPKI_ERROR External Certificate Signing Failed⏎
[Dec 13, 2021, 21:32:41] Client exception in transport_recv_excode: 
OpenSSLContext::SSL::read_cleartext: BIO_read failed, cap=2576 status=-1: error:0607907F:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA:expecting an rsa key / error:141F0006:SSL routines:tls_construct_cert_verify:EVP lib
[Dec 13, 2021, 21:32:41] EVENT: DISCONNECTED ⏎
```

The client config is:

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
ifconfig 10.3.0.1 255.255.255.0

ca C:\\Users\\User1\\openvpnkeys\\ca.crt
tls-crypt C:\\Users\\User1\\openvpnkeys\\tls.key
cipher AES-256-GCM
auth SHA256

ping 10
comp-lzo
verb 4
mute 10
```

Client and server certificates have been created by easy-rsa installed on the server comp.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. The problem was in the links. I've put certificates in the body of the config file and the client has connected successfully.

I have to say the log is rather poor.